# tell CMake to link to Boost in a custom folder

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, cmake, g++

I'm trying to install boost in a custom dir. I did:

```
cd boost_dir
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/custom_dir
./b2
```

Now what I want to do is tell CMake to point to that library. To that end, I added:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "/custom_dir")
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myProject ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

And CMake apparently found boost in that dir:

```
cmake .                                                                                                                                                                                     
-- Found Boost: /custom_dir (found suitable version "1.66.0", minimum required is "1.66") found components: program_options                                                                                 -- Configuring done                                                                                                                                                                                                           
-- Generating done                        
-- Build files have been written to: /my_project
```

However, when compiling, I still get:

```
undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
```

A few answers have noted that boost must have been compiled with the same compiler as the program I'm using. However, I'm not sure if the steps I did above actually compiled boost or simply copies the uncompressed libs?

Also, does it use the path-resolved g++ or something in the system default /usr/bin? Reason is that I do not have root access and installed an updated GCC in a custom dir as well. I've pointed my PATH to the updated g++.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, the GCC version was correct but it would only work if I compiled Boost with static linking and told CMake to link statically. I experimented with dynamic linking (both compiling Boost and setting CMake for my target app) and it doesn't work for some reason.

Just make sure to compile with the same ABI options.